# Speedup setTextFormat()

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, performance, textfield

i've a text with a very long list of words to highlight and calling setTextFormat() one for each word takes ages. There's some way to speedup this operation ? i've tried with a TextField not instantiate in the DisplayObject's list, to bypass the rendering stage but i've founded that the performance are the same. Any ideas ?

Comment: How long is the list of words?  Is it every word in the list or are you pulling out specific words?  What parameters of TextFormat are you setting?  Can you post your sample code setting up the TextFormat object and using setTextFormat()?

Comment: there are 60k ranges of text that i want to highlight with different styles and colors. I run a for cycle over a Vector of Tokens that i've founded previously and for each token i call textField.setTextFormat(token.styleInfo.format, token.begin, token.end); where textField is a TextField instance and token.styleInfo.format is a TextFormat instance. In my test coloring 60k tokens takes 8 minutes

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to strongly suggest you take a look at the Text Layout Framework's new mode of handling rich text styling.

Essentially, the TLF has a TextFlow object that contains a model of your text, including all relevant span-specific formatting.  This is distinct from the "view" portion of text display, which would be managed (in your case of edit-able text) by a separate flow composer and EditManager.

Thus, you can perform formatting transformations on wide swaths of the text model, and only have the view re-draw itself on command at the very end.

Comment: Hi, i've converted the code using Text Layout Framework, my code takes a Vector of token and for each token calls

var selection:SelectionState = new SelectionState(this._textFlow, begin, end, normalFormat);

where begin, and end are two integers that represent the area to colorize and 
IEditManager(_textFlow.interactionManager).applyLeafFormat(format, selection);
apply my format (an instance of TextLayoutFormat). Everything seems to work but it's 10 times slower than the previous version. I've done any error ? are there any clever solution (i'm sure about it...) ?

Answer (score 1):

Use TLF, and before you start coloring everything call beginCompositeOperation(); and at the end call _objEditManager.endCompositeOperation();  Here's a sample right out of my code

```
_objFlow.interactionManager = _objEditManager;
                    _objEditManager.beginCompositeOperation();

                    DocColoringUtils.SetRegionColor(_objFlow, iStart, iEnd, BackgroundColor.TRANSPARENT, 1);

                    var colRegions:Vector.<Region> = _objResourceMediator.GetCurrentResourceRegions();
                    var objEditingExcerpt:Excerpt = _objExcerptingMediator.EditingExcerpt;

                    if (_objExcerptingMediator.InEditMode == true && objEditingExcerpt != null)
                    {
                        DocColoringUtils.ColorizeForEditMode(_objFlow, iStart, iEnd, colRegions, objEditingExcerpt.StartIndex, objEditingExcerpt.EndIndex, _objExcerptingMediator.SearchMatchRegions);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DocColoringUtils.ColorizeForNonEditMode(_objFlow, iStart, iEnd, colRegions, _objExcerptingMediator.SearchMatchRegions);
                    }
                    _objEditManager.endCompositeOperation();

                    _objFlow.interactionManager = _objSelectionManager;
```

Finally, you should only color whats in viewable range +/- 300 characters.  Then on scrolling recolor the current viewable region.  This works for some insanely large document on http://www.Dedoose.com.

Answer (score 0):

if its a htmlText and the words that you wanna to highlight are put in tags like `<strong>` you should look at the [StyleSheet](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html) Object you can define its styles by [loading a css file](http://snipplr.com/view/11620/css-for-styling-text-in-flash-with-nonstandard-fonts/) or you can assign the styles like this:

```
var style:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
var strong:Object = new Object(); 
strong.textDecoration = "underline";
style.setStyle("strong", strong);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've checked htmlText and i know that it's way faster then setTextFormat() but the problem is that i have to reapply colors when user changes the text and using htmlText i have to blank the area and replace htmlText with a new version and the user see the TextArea blink, and the text moved to the end. Using setTextFormat() i can change only small part of the text during text changes

Comment: you could change this bug into a feature, just fadeout nicely the text, change it, and fade it in again. but i don't really understand how the user can change a htmlText.

Comment: well the user interact with a component similar to a standard Flex TextArea so it can change the content by typing or using cut/paste. I have a listener for the CHANGE event that update the inner textField to reflect content changes. If the user write something i have to colorize the text again and using htmlText it means that i have to pass a new string to htmlText